# Android - set ImageView dimension Bigger than Window View

Tags: android

I am trying to stretch the `imageView` 3 times bigger than the window screen mobile. However, it seems to not work if I want the view bigger.

```
int WindowWidth = UtilityClass.getWindowWidth();
int WindowHeight = UtilityClass.getWindowHeight();

bk_main = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bk_main);

bk_main.getLayoutParams().width = WindowWidth * 3;
bk_main.getLayoutParams().height = WindowHeight * 3;
bk_main.requestLayout();
```

Using the code the `imageView` get stretch but is not going outside the mobile window margins.
How could I do this?

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.livectlab.gml.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bk"
        android:id="@+id/bk_main"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="@string/bk_description"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to rotate the background image without leaving empty spaces

[image]

Comment: Can you post your XML layout, please?

Comment: Just added The XML

Comment: You changed size of ImageView, but it's also have parent (RelativeLayout) constraints. Do you want to set bigger size and obtain scrollable behavior for ImageView?

Comment: No I want to infinite rotate the image in background without leaving empty background

Comment: And if you resize the image then put it in the image view with `scaleType=centerCrop` ?

Comment: I have tried but is not working

Comment: I have added a picture to show you the problem

Comment: Can you give the image, so i can test something ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you need to use matrix for such purposes, check scaleType matrix and method setImageMatrix

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier It can be tested with any image 320x480